# Desktop doesn't start after upgrade to Ubuntu 20

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, lvm, desktop, dist-upgrade

I've a dual boot ( windows + ubuntu ) with grub2.

I had Ubuntu 16 and I upgraded it via UI ( I was informed about some crashes about packages it couldn't get, but the process continued until the very end ).

After this, windows works normally but Desktop doesn't start showing the following message:

`ln: /tmp/mountroot-fail-hooks.d//scripts/init-premount/lvm2: No such file or directory`

I guess that's all information I have.

Thanks in advance.

Update:

I have all terminals working ( ctrl+alt+f2-7 ), desktop does not start and I just got the line I mentioned above ( log referring to lvm2 ) and the blinking caret. If I switch between tty's like a crazy man, sometimes, when I go to the desktop one, desktop appears for a fraction of a second. My GPU is XFX RX 5500 XT Thicc II Pro.

I wanted to go from 16 to 18, and then 18 to 20, obviusly, but Ubuntu's upgrade system didn't show any option about OS version target and went straight to 20, so I guessed it would manage to get it done right.

Update 2: 
[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to unplug monitors from GPU, plug it directly to motherboard's gpu & restart pc, but doesn't work this way neither.

Grub screen use to be purple, now it's black.

Comment: I think you mean your desktop isn't starting, UI [or UX] doesn't have any meaning in this context, anything is a UI, including the console command line interface. Try posting more information, are you getting a black monitor, or a monitor where you see one blinking white line? Are you seeing your login screen? The error message you posted to is unlikely to have any relevance. Which ubuntu did you try upgrading to? Trying to go 16 to 20 would be unlikely to succeed unless you were very lucky. What is your graphics card, etc? Use words to describe what is happening.

Comment: I have all terminals working ( ctrl+alt+f2-7 ), desktop does not start and I just got the line I mentioned above ( log referring to lvm2 ) and the blinking caret. If I switch between tty's like a crazy man, sometimes, when I go to the desktop one, desktop appears for a fraction of a second.

My GPU is XFX RX 5500 XT Thicc II Pro.

And I wanted to go from 16 to 18, and then 18 to 20, obviusly, but Ubuntu's upgrade system didn't show any option about OS version target and went straight to 20, so I guessed it would manage to get it done right.

Comment: You might look/ask on sister site askubuntu.com where there is a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1235344/421483).

Comment: The blinking caret means your video driver didn't load. When supplying graphics card info, make sure not to forget the actual vendor/type, otherwise I have to look it up. It's an AMD, which suggests that you may have had a legacy amd driver in your xorg.conf, which you can see with: cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | tail -n 60 [in most cases anyway, that's where the failure to load the display driver would appear, though it's not certain]. Also try, and add to your post: inxi -bzxx

Comment: Could you please edit your post to include the information you wrote as comments in the question? Otherwise it is difficult to get a clear picture, as comments are cumbersome to read (and volatile).

Comment: @Lizardx Are you sure it can be possible when, at some point and for a few milliseconds, I can see the login screen? ( I said that on comments, so maybe u did not see it. Now is in issue body ). Thanks m8.

Comment: Pretty sure, yes. Read your /var/log/Xorg.0.log, last 50 to 100 lines, that usually shows what failed. Your screenshot show a bunch of drivers loaded, which should not be the case, and none with FAILED. My guess is it's loading for a split second, then crashing due to something inconsistent somewhere, could be in /etc/X11/xorg.conf, might be specifying a driver that doesn't work, hard to say.

Comment: @Lizardx Do you think has something to do with the last screenshot? "AMDGPU (0): [KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported".

Comment: the more random actions you take, like configuring xorg.conf for root, the less likely you will be able to resolve the issue in my opinion. It looks like your config files, and probably the xorg log files, are going to the newer $HOME/.config and .local/share locations. It's not really practical to offer this type of support though, I stopped doing it years ago. The proper action when debugging issues is 1: find what is wrong 2: correct what is wrong

Comment: I'm agree, more variables more complex becomes the problem. Thank you anyway for your guidance, at least now I'm able to keep looking. I was stucked. 

Have a nice night.

Comment: Find all your xorg.conf files and rename them to something else, append a -bu to the file name for example, just get rid of all of them, let xorg do its thing, after reboot, then check the xorg error log and see what happened. Don't do what you are doing, that just leads to harder and harder debugging and diagnosing. Use: updatedb THEN locate xorg.conf to find all of the xorg.conf files, then rename them all, then reboot, then see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108516/discussion-between-xpeiro-and-lizardx).

Comment: Nah, I don't do individual support anymore, been there, done that.

Comment: Ty anyway, you have been pretty useful.